# Admin URL strange

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

i just installed magento for the first time, and i notice that after installation i cant login to administration, in my console network it gives me a 302 code, im not sure, but is it possibile to be my url is wrong? This is given to me automataclly when i go to admin panel:

URL:
http://magendo.development/admin/admin/index/index/key/7a6d73bee30f884c430d3603e180f4f1f25641443196442eea2851e1ffc041a4/

Is it normal to appear duplicate admin and index?

Configuration and details:

Site url: magendo.development

Site url admin: magendo.development/admin

Magento ver 2.0.5

Vanilla Instalation

PHP 5.6.3

Apache 2.4

Local Host;

Windows 10

VHost Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Define MAGENTO_ROOT "c:/development/magento"

    DocumentRoot ${MAGENTO_ROOT}

    ServerName magendo.development

    RewriteEngine On
    #LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8

    <Directory ${MAGENTO_ROOT}>
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Have you got any custom modules installed, or is this a vanilla installation? What kind of web server are you using, what is your host name in the web server configuration? What is the base URL for the admin (default) store level in your database?

Comment: @RobbieAverill just updated the post with the information

Comment: The admin base URL should be just that, a base URL. If you're just using `/admin` then don't include it in the base URL - leave it matching your frontend URLs. the `/admin` is added by Magento configuration

Comment: Ok @RobbieAverill , so why cant i login in the Administration and gives me a 302 code?

Comment: Because you've already got `/admin` in your base URL, so it's adding it again. Take it out so your admin base URL is just `magento.development`, clear your cache and try again

Comment: @RobbieAverill but the problem is magento adding it automatclly, if i remove it he adds it. For example i put magento.development/admin and magento add the duplicate of admin and index, and if i remove admin it adds it.

Comment: A base URL is a configuration setting defined in your database, under the `core_config_data` table. Please clarify.

Comment: @RobbieAverill i just checked and it doesnt have nothing there, the base url is already set has magento.development, here is the link of configurations image http://i.imgur.com/S6TIvSy.png